# How to use custom class annotation in testng listener java

Tags: java, annotations, testng

I created a method level java custom annotation like below

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Test {

    public String id() default "0";
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class test {

    @Test
    @Test(id = "231")
    public void test_section(){
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }   
}
```

i was able to use the value of id using below code line

```
result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(Test.class).id();
```

Now i want to create a class level custom java annotation as below

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface section {

    public String Name() default "0";   
}
```

and use the same annotation in my test class and get the value of Name in the testng listener **ITestListener** onTestStart method as i am using testng to execute the test case, below is the test class

```
@section(Name="u_id")
public class testcustom {

    @Test
    public void test_section(){
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }   
}
```

I am unable to get the value of section, How to get the value of name in section annotation used on class level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the API, something like

```
void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
  section annotation = result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getAnnotation(section.class);
  if (annotation != null) {
    // do something with annotation.Name()
  }
}
```

should work (note that Java naming conventions mean it should be `Section` and `name()` instead).

Comment: Thanks, the above code worked for me and also for pointing out the naming convention mistakes:)